# htaccess url rewrite rule in conflict with folder name

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^models$  index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^post$  index.php?action=post [L]
```

and a folder named `models`.

The problem is: Apache sends me into the folder. With "post" the redirect rule works as there is no folder named post.

EDIT:
I forgot to tell that there is htaccess in models folder too, with:

```
Deny from all
```

Comment: So you would like `http://example.com/models`to be rewritten to `index.php`, but not `http://example.com/models/`?

Comment: yes, and I tried RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
    RewriteRule (.*)  index.php [L]

Comment: turn off Multiviews and DirectoryIndex if you don't use them.

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept a trailing slash after models, I think this would work.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^models/?$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^post$ index.php?action=post& [L]
```

Comment: Strange. I tested it on my server and it worked with my environment (having an models folder. Can you please tell us exactly which tests you are running to validate your configuration?

Comment: I forgot to tell that there is htaccess in models folder too, with:      Deny from all

Answer (score 0):

disable MultiViews in your apache configuration file. 
adding "Options -MultiViews" to your .htaccess might work too.